# Everytime I jump with my character it says its hit even though it hasn't

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, pygame, collision

I am trying to get a collision with my animation and when I jump it says I hit the hitbox, even though I have not.

Here is a link to a video with the problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kHfdd2RPzU9IT9wfAss4QQXjlnwv40ut/view?usp=sharing

I have tried changing the conditions of which the collision happens, I tried searching for different ways to do hitbox such as sprite,but I dont understand how to do that. I am fairly new at programming so I dont what else I should try.

```
from time import sleep as s
import random
import pygame
import time
from pygame import *
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100,16,2,4096)
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("Arcade Game Music Type Beat (Hip-HopRB Instrumental).mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.7)
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

window = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Practice Game")
image = pygame.image.load('pixel6.png')
image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (1000, 500))

jumpv1 = [pygame.image.load('adventurer-jump-00.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-jump-01.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-jump-02.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-jump-03.png'), pygame.image.load('adventurer-smrslt-00.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-smrslt-01.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-smrslt-02.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-smrslt-03.png')]
jumpv2 = [pygame.image.load('adventurer-smrslt-00.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-smrslt-01.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-smrslt-02.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-smrslt-03.png')]
jumpv3 = [pygame.image.load('adventurer-smrslt-00.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-smrslt-01.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-smrslt-02.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-smrslt-03.png')]
jumpv4 = [pygame.image.load('adventurer-smrslt-00.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-smrslt-01.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-smrslt-02.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-smrslt-03.png')]
jump1 = jumpv1+jumpv2+jumpv3+jumpv4

run2 = [pygame.image.load('adventurer-run-00.png'), pygame.image.load('adventurer-run-01.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-run-02.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-run-03.png')]

slide1 = [pygame.image.load('adventurer-slide-00.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-slide-01.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-stand-00.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-stand-01.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-stand-02.png')]

firstattack = [pygame.image.load('adventurer-attack3-00.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-attack3-01.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-attack3-02.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-attack3-03.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-attack3-04.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-attack3-05.png')]
secondattack = [pygame.image.load('adventurer-attack2-00.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-attack2-01.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-attack2-02.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-attack2-03.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-attack2-04.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-attack2-05.png')]
thirdattack = [pygame.image.load('adventurer-attack1-00.png'),pygame.image  .load('adventurer-attack1-01.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-attack1-02.png'),pygame.image.load('adventurer-attack1-03.png'), pygame.image.load('adventurer-attack1-04.png')]

falling = [pygame.image.load('adventurer-fall-00.png'), pygame.image.load('adventurer-fall-01.png')]                               

attack = firstattack+secondattack+ thirdattack


run = True
for i in range (20):
    jump1[i] = pygame.transform.scale(jump1[i],(90,90))
for i in range(3):
    run2[i] = pygame.transform.scale(run2[i],(90,90))
for i in range (4): 
    slide1[i] = pygame.transform.scale(slide1[i],(90,90))
for i in range (1):
    falling[i] = pygame.transform.scale(falling[i],(90,90))
for i in range(16):
    attack[i] = pygame.transform.scale(attack[i],(90,90))
imagex = 0
imagex2 = image.get_width()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

img1 = pygame.image.load('imgg.png')
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, (0,0,0))
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((1000/2),(500/2))
    window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()

def death():
    message_display('You DIED')
class obstacles(object):
    img = [pygame.image.load('imgg.png'),pygame.image.load('imgg.png')]
    def __init__(self, x,y, width1, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self.width1 = width1
        self.height = height
        self.hitbox = (x,y,100,100)
        self.count = 0

    def draw(self, window):
        self.hitbox = (self.x+46, self.y, 45, 60)
        if self.count >=1:
            self.count = 0
        self.count +=1
        window.blit(pygame.transform.scale(self.img[self.count], (150,100)), (self.x, self.y-15)) 
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), self.hitbox, 2)

    def hit(self):
        print ("hit")

class obstacles2(object):
    walkleft = pygame.image.load('obstc2.png')
    def __init__(self, x,y, width2, height2):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self.width2 = width2
        self.height2 = height2
        self.hitbox_enemy = (x,y,200,100)
        self.count1 = 0
    def draw(self, window):
        self.hitbox_enemy = (self.x, self.y, 65, 65)
        window.blit(pygame.transform.scale(self.walkleft, (65,65)), (self.x, self.y)) 
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), self.hitbox_enemy, 2)

class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.vel = 0.5
        self.run1 = True
        self.jump2 = True
        self.slide2 = True
        self.attack1 = True
        self.isJump = False
        self. jumps = True
        self.falling1 = True
        self.player_x = 40
        self.player_y = 378
        self.x = 40
        self.y = 378
        self.width = 378
        self.speed = 0.6
        self.jumpcount = 10
        self.jumpcount1 = 0
        self.runcount = 0
        self.attack2 = 0
        self.slide = 0       
        self.fallspeed = 0.3
        self.falling2 = 0
        self.hitbox = (self.player_x,self.player_y,90,90)
        self.hitbox2 = (45,self.player_y+47,65,45)
        self.hitbox3 = (self.player_x+30,self.player_y,35,80)
        self.hitbox4 = (self.player_x+20,self.player_y+20,52,55)
        self.hitbox5 = (58,405,47,70)
        self.hitbox6 = (108, 405, 20, 50)


    def movement(self, window):
        pygame.time.delay(20)
        if self.runcount >= 3:
            self.runcount = 0

        if self.run1 == True:
            window.blit(run2[self.runcount],(int(self.player_x),int(self.player_y)))
            self.runcount +=1
            self.hitbox = (self.player_x+30,self.player_y+20,48,70)
            pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),self.hitbox, 2)

        if (keys[pygame.K_DOWN]) or ((keys[pygame.K_DOWN]) and keys[pygame.K_p]):
            if self.player_y == 378:
                self.run1 = False
                if self.slide >= 4:
                    self.slide = 0

                if self.slide2:  
                    window.blit(slide1[self.slide],(int(self.player_x),int(self.player_y)))
                    self.slide +=1
                    pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),self.hitbox2, 2)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if (event.key == pygame.K_DOWN )and self.player_y < self.width:

                self.run1 = False
                self.jump2 = False
                self.fallspeed += 0.2

                if self.falling2 >= 1:
                    self.falling2 = 0
                if self.falling1:
                    window.blit(falling[self.falling2], (int(self.player_x),int(self.player_y)))
                    self.hitbox3 = (self.player_x+30,self.player_y,35,80)
                    pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),self.hitbox3, 2)                    
                    self.falling2 +=1
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and keys[pygame.K_p] :
            self.fallspeed = 0.3
            self.run1 = False
            self.jump2 = False
            self.slide2 = False
            if self.attack2 >= 16:
                self.attack2 = 0
            if self.attack1: 
                window.blit(attack[self.attack2],(int(self.player_x),int(self.player_y)))
                self.attack2 += 1
                self.hitbox5 = (self.player_x+30,self.player_y+20,38,70)
                self.hitbox6 = (self.player_x+72, self.player_y+20, 20, 50)
                pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),self.hitbox5, 2)
                pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),self.hitbox6, 2)
            if self.jumpcount1 >= 20:
                self.jumpcount1 = 0
            if self.jump2 and self.player_y < self.width:  
                window.blit(jump1[self.jumpcount1],(int(self.player_x),int(self.player_y)))
                self.hitbox4 = (int(self.player_x+20),int(self.player_y+20),52,55)
                pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),self.hitbox4, 2)
                self.jumpcount1 +=1
                self.fallspeed = 0.3

        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.fallspeed = 0.3
            self.run1 = False
            if self.jumpcount1 >= 20:
                self.jumpcount1 = 0

            if self.jump2 and self.player_y < self.width:  
                window.blit(jump1[self.jumpcount1],(int(self.player_x),int(self.player_y)))
                self.hitbox4 = (int(self.player_x+20),int(self.player_y+20),52,55)
                pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),self.hitbox4, 2)
                self.jumpcount1 +=1
                self.fallspeed = 0.3

        if keys[pygame.K_p] and not keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.run1 = False
            self.jump2 = False
            self.slide2 = False
            if self.attack2 >= 16:
                self.attack2 = 0

            if self.attack1:
                self.hitbox5 = (self.player_x+30,self.player_y+20,38,70)
                self.hitbox6 = (self.player_x+72, self.player_y+20, 20, 50)
                window.blit(attack[self.attack2],(int(self.player_x),int(self.player_y)))
                self.attack2 += 1
                pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),self.hitbox5, 2)
                pygame.draw.rect(window,(255,0,0),self.hitbox6, 2)
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.run1 = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.run1 = True
                self.jump2 = True
                self.fallspeed = 0.3

            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.run1=True
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                self.run1 = True
                self.jump2 = True
                self.slide2 = True

class enemy(object):
    walkright = [pygame.image.load('R1E.png'), pygame.image.load('R2E.png'), pygame.image.load('R3E.png'), pygame.image.load('R4E.png'), pygame.image.load('R5E.png'), pygame.image.load('R6E.png'), pygame.image.load('R7E.png'), pygame.image.load('R8E.png'), pygame.image.load('R9E.png'), pygame.image.load('R10E.png'), pygame.image.load('R11E.png')]
    walkleft = [pygame.image.load('L1E.png'), pygame.image.load('L2E.png'), pygame.image.load('L3E.png'), pygame.image.load('L4E.png'), pygame.image.load('L5E.png'), pygame.image.load('L6E.png'), pygame.image.load('L7E.png'), pygame.image.load('L8E.png'), pygame.image.load('L9E.png'), pygame.image.load('L10E.png'), pygame.image.load('L11E.png')]
    for i in range (10):
        walkright[i] = pygame.transform.scale(walkright[i],(70,70))
    for i in range(10):
        walkleft[i] = pygame.transform.scale(walkleft[i],(70,70))

    def __init__(self,enemy_x,enemy_y, end):
        self.x = enemy_x
        self.y = enemy_y             
        self.end = end

        self.path = [self.x,self.end]
        self.walkcount = 0
        self.vel = 7
        self.hitbox = (self.x,self.y-15,90,90)

    def draw_enemy(self,window):
        self.move()
        if self.walkcount+1 >= 33:
            self.walkcount = 0
        #walking right
        if self.vel > 0:
            window.blit(self.walkleft[self.walkcount//3], (self.x,self.y-15))
            self.walkcount += 1
        #walking left
        if self.vel < 0:
##            window.blit(self.walkleft[self.walkcount//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkcount -= 1
        if self.x < -100:
            self.x = 1050
        self.hitbox = (self.x+25,self.y-15,41,70)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0),self.hitbox,2)

    def move(self):
        if self.vel > 0:
            #see if position + movement space is < the end, then it is able to move
            if self.x + self.vel < self.path[1]:
                self.x -= self.vel
            #past end point and turns 180
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel*-1
                self.walkcount = 0
        #see if position is smaller than starting position
        else:
            if self.x - self.vel > self.path[0]:
                #vel is already negative
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
               #Truns 180 agian
               self.vel = self.vel* -1
               self.walkcount = 0

objects = []
object2 = []
def keepdrawing():
    window.blit(image, (imagex,0))
    window.blit(image, (imagex2,0))
    for object1 in objects:
        object1.draw(window)
    for object3 in object2:

        object3.draw(window)
    adventurer.movement(window)
    attacker.draw_enemy(window)
    pygame.display.update()
attacker = enemy(950,407,951)
adventurer = player(40,387)
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT+2,random.randint(2000, 3000))
while run2:
    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        imagex -= 2
        imagex2 -= 2
        if imagex < image.get_width() * -1:
            imagex = image.get_width()
        if imagex2 < image.get_width() * -1:
            imagex2 = image.get_width()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if adventurer.hitbox[0] > attacker.hitbox[0] and adventurer.hitbox[0]+30 < attacker.hitbox[0]+70:
            if  adventurer.hitbox[1] > attacker.hitbox[1] and adventurer.hitbox[1] < attacker.hitbox[1]+70:
                    window.fill((255,255,255)) 
                    death()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    s(0.1)
                    print("hit")
        if  (keys[pygame.K_DOWN]) and adventurer.hitbox2[0] > attacker.hitbox[0] and adventurer.hitbox2[0] < attacker.hitbox[0]+70:
            if  adventurer.hitbox2[1] > attacker.hitbox[1] and adventurer.hitbox2[1]+70 > attacker.hitbox[1]:
                    window.fill((255,255,255))
                    death()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    s(0.1)
                    print("hit")
        if (keys[pygame.K_DOWN]) and adventurer.hitbox3[0]+70 < 391 and adventurer.hitbox3[0] > attacker.hitbox[0] and adventurer.hitbox3[0] < attacker.hitbox[0]+70:
            if  adventurer.hitbox3[1] > attacker.hitbox[1] and adventurer.hitbox3[1] < attacker.hitbox[1]+50:
                    window.fill((255,255,255))
                    death()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    s(0.1)
                    print("hit")

        if  (keys[pygame.K_UP])and adventurer.hitbox4[0] > attacker.hitbox[0] and adventurer.hitbox4[0] < attacker.hitbox[0]+70:
            if  adventurer.hitbox4[1] > attacker.hitbox[1] and adventurer.hitbox4[1] < attacker.hitbox[1]+50:
                    window.fill((255,255,255))
                    death()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    s(0.1)
                    print("hit")
        if  (keys[pygame.K_UP])and adventurer.hitbox5[0] > attacker.hitbox[0] and adventurer.hitbox5[0] < attacker.hitbox[0]+70:
            if  adventurer.hitbox5[1] > attacker.hitbox[1] and adventurer.hitbox5[1] < attacker.hitbox[1]+50:
                    window.fill((255,255,255))
                    death()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    s(0.1)
                    print("hit")
        if  (keys[pygame.K_p] and (adventurer.hitbox6[0] > attacker.hitbox[0])) and adventurer.hitbox6[0] < attacker.hitbox[0]+70:
            if  adventurer.hitbox6[1] > attacker.hitbox[1] and adventurer.hitbox6[1] < attacker.hitbox[1]+50:
                    attacker.x = 1050 
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                exit()
            if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+1:
                adventurer.speed += 1
            if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+2:
                r = random.randint(0,1)
                if r==0:
                    new_obstacle2 = obstacles2(1050, 390, 64,64)
                    object2.append(new_obstacle2)
                if r==1:
                    new_obstacle = obstacles(1050,390,64,64)
                    objects.append(new_obstacle)
        for object3 in object2:
            if adventurer.hitbox[0] > object3.hitbox_enemy[0] and adventurer.hitbox[0] < object3.hitbox_enemy[0]+85:
                if  adventurer.hitbox[1] > object3.hitbox_enemy[1] and adventurer.hitbox[1] < object3.hitbox_enemy[1]+50:
                    window.fill((255,255,255))
                    death()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    s(0.1)
                    print("hit")
            if  (keys[pygame.K_DOWN]) and adventurer.hitbox2[0] > object3.hitbox_enemy[0] and adventurer.hitbox2[0] < object3.hitbox_enemy[0]+85:
                if  adventurer.hitbox2[1] > object3.hitbox_enemy[1] and adventurer.hitbox2[1]+70 > object3.hitbox_enemy[1]:
                    window.fill((255,255,255))
                    death()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    s(0.1)
                    print("hit")
            if (keys[pygame.K_DOWN])and adventurer.hitbox3[0]+70 < 391 and adventurer.hitbox3[0] > object3.hitbox_enemy[0] and adventurer.hitbox3[0] < object3.hitbox_enemy[0]+85:
                if  adventurer.hitbox3[1] > object3.hitbox_enemy[1] and adventurer.hitbox3[1] < object3.hitbox_enemy[1]+50:
                    window.fill((255,255,255))
                    death()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    s(0.1)
                    print("hit")

            if  (keys[pygame.K_UP])and adventurer.hitbox4[0] > object3.hitbox_enemy[0] and adventurer.hitbox4[0] < object3.hitbox_enemy[0]+85:
                if  adventurer.hitbox4[1] > object3.hitbox_enemy[1] and adventurer.hitbox4[1] < object3.hitbox_enemy[1]+50:
                    window.fill((255,255,255))
                    death()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    s(0.1)
                    print("hit")
            if  (keys[pygame.K_UP])and adventurer.hitbox5[0] > object3.hitbox_enemy[0] and adventurer.hitbox5[0] < object3.hitbox_enemy[0]+85:
                if  adventurer.hitbox5[1] > object3.hitbox_enemy[1] and adventurer.hitbox5[1] < object3.hitbox_enemy[1]+50:
                    window.fill((255,255,255))
                    death()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    s(0.1)
                    print("hit")
            if  (keys[pygame.K_p] and (adventurer.hitbox6[0] > object3.hitbox_enemy[0])) and adventurer.hitbox6[0] < object3.hitbox_enemy[0]+86:
                if  adventurer.hitbox6[1] > object3.hitbox_enemy[1] and adventurer.hitbox6[1] < object3.hitbox_enemy[1]+50:
                    object2.pop(object2.index(object3))
            object3.x -=7
            if object3.x < -100:
                object2.pop(object2.index(object3))      
        for object1 in objects:
            if adventurer.hitbox[0] > object1.hitbox[0] and adventurer.hitbox[0] < object1.hitbox[0]+70:
                if  adventurer.hitbox[1] > object1.hitbox[1] and adventurer.hitbox[1] < object1.hitbox[1]+50:
                    window.fill((255,255,255))
                    death()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    s(0.1)
                    print("hit")
            if  (keys[pygame.K_DOWN]) and adventurer.hitbox2[0] > object1.hitbox[0] and adventurer.hitbox2[0] < object1.hitbox[0]+70:
                if  adventurer.hitbox2[1] > object1.hitbox[1] and adventurer.hitbox2[1]+70 > object1.hitbox[1]:
                    window.fill((255,255,255))
                    death()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    s(0.1)
                    print("hit")
            if (keys[pygame.K_DOWN])and adventurer.hitbox3[0]+70 < 391 and adventurer.hitbox3[0] > object1.hitbox[0] and adventurer.hitbox3[0] < object1.hitbox[0]+70:
                if  adventurer.hitbox3[1] > object1.hitbox[1] and adventurer.hitbox3[1] < object1.hitbox[1]+50:
                    window.fill((255,255,255))
                    death()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    s(0.1)
                    print("hit")

            if  (keys[pygame.K_UP])and adventurer.hitbox4[0] > object1.hitbox[0] and adventurer.hitbox4[0] < object1.hitbox[0]+70:
                if  adventurer.hitbox4[1] > object1.hitbox[1] and adventurer.hitbox4[1] < object1.hitbox[1]+50:
                    window.fill((255,255,255))
                    death()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    s(0.1)
                    print("hit")
            if  (keys[pygame.K_UP])and adventurer.hitbox5[0] > object1.hitbox[0] and adventurer.hitbox5[0] < object1.hitbox[0]+70:
                if  adventurer.hitbox5[1] > object1.hitbox[1] and adventurer.hitbox5[1] < object1.hitbox[1]+50:
                    window.fill((255,255,255))
                    death()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    s(0.1)
                    print("hit")
            if  (keys[pygame.K_p] and (adventurer.hitbox6[0] > object1.hitbox[0])) and adventurer.hitbox6[0] < object1.hitbox[0]+70:
                if  adventurer.hitbox6[1] > object1.hitbox[1] and adventurer.hitbox6[1] < object1.hitbox[1]+50:
                    objects.pop(objects.index(object1))
            object1.x -= 7
            if object1.x < -100:
                objects.pop(objects.index(object1))



        if not(adventurer.isJump):

            if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                adventurer.isJump =True

        else:

            if adventurer.jumpcount >= -10:

                neg=1
                if adventurer.player_y > adventurer.width:
                    adventurer.player_y = adventurer.width
                if adventurer.jumpcount <0:
                    neg = -1
    ##                s(0.01)
                adventurer.player_y -= (adventurer.jumpcount**2)*adventurer.fallspeed*neg*2
    ##            s(0.01)
                adventurer.jumpcount -=1

                if adventurer.player_y > adventurer.width:
                    adventurer.player_y=adventurer.width

            else:
                adventurer.isJump = False
                adventurer.jumpcount = 10
                if adventurer.player_y > adventurer.width:
                    player_y = adventurer.width
                    adventurer.fallspeed = 0.05
        keepdrawing()
```

Sorry for the long code, but all of it is needed to understand how it is and the end result should be that it should only show "you DIED" when the boxes hit each other, not when jumped on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like this could be the culprit.

{if  adventurer.hitbox[1] > attacker.hitbox[1] and adventurer.hitbox[1] < attacker.hitbox[1]+70:}

You're comparing the y coordinate of the adventurer's hitboz to the y coord of the attacker's, which is all good. But then you check if the adventurer's y coord is less than 70 units higher than the attacker's y coord. So, my thought is that maybe your jump isn't going high enough to account for 70 units of distance.  I'm not all that great with pyGame, but this was my best shot from just reading your code.

Comment: that did not fix the problem sir.